# InlineFormFactory Column 'book_id' cannot be null

Tags: python, django

Ok i am doing the test. I want to upload some pdf files. so i follow the formset tutorial

but seems like one error is coming  that is

```
(1048, "Column 'book_id' cannot be null")
```

This is the model class.

```
class Book(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(Author)#,  null=True, blank=True)
     album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class Book_File(models.Model):
     filefile = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
     book = models.ForeignKey(Book)#,  null=True, blank=True)
```

And the ModelForm looks this

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book_File
        fields = ['filefile', 'book']

BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Book, Book_File, extra=3, can_delete=False)
book = Book.objects.get(book_name=u'New')
formset = AlbumFormSet(instance=book)
```

If i put book_id in viewalbum  as suggested in django tutorial the error comming

```
def viewalbum(request,book_id):
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=book)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for data in formset.cleaned_data:
                Book_File.objects.create(filefile=data['filefile'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('first.views.viewalbum'))
    else:
        formset = BookFormSet(instance=book)
    return render_to_response('test.html',{'formset': formset})
```

Tell me what i missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving data as

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for data in formset.cleaned_data:
        Book_File.objects.create(filefile=data['filefile'])
```

Here you are creating the `Book_File` object but not specifying the `book` instance. You should do

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for data in formset.cleaned_data:
        Book_File.objects.create(filefile=data['filefile'], book=book)
```

Or rather just do

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

Comment: Well. What with this error viewalbum() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @gello, I don't know what you are referring to.